# Laravel Query Builder does not work correctly

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

I am trying to do an advanced join with laravel, which looks like this:

```
$locations = DB::table('location')
        ->select('location.location_time',
                'heart_rate.heartrate'  
        )
        ->leftJoin('heart_rate' , function($join) use ($data) {
                $join->on('heart_rate.user_id', '=', DB::raw('1'))
                    ->where('heart_rate.time', '>',  DB::raw('(location.location_time - INTERVAL 5 SECOND)')) //   ->whereBetween('heart_rate.time', array(, DB::raw('location.location_time + 2 SECOND')));
                    ->where('heart_rate.time', '<',  DB::raw('(location.location_time + INTERVAL 5 SECOND)'));     
                })
        ->where('location.user_id', '=',  DB::raw('1'))
        ->whereBetween('location.location_time', array( "2015-04-24 00:00:00", "2015-04-25 23:59:59" ))
        ->get();
```

which returns the following: `[{"location_time":"2015-04-24 14:00:00","heartrate":null}]`

When I let it dump the query and type it directely into mySQL however, i get the following result : [image], which is how it should be, as  the tables from the database are:

Table 'heart_rate' : [image]

Table 'location'   : [image]

The SQL Query i dump is

```
SELECT 
  `location`.`location_time`,
  `heart_rate`.`heartrate` 
FROM
  `location` 
  LEFT JOIN `heart_rate` 
    ON `heart_rate`.`user_id` = 1 
    AND `heart_rate`.`time` > (
      location.location_time - INTERVAL 5 SECOND
    ) 
    AND `heart_rate`.`time` < (
      location.location_time + INTERVAL 5 SECOND
    ) 
WHERE `location`.`user_id` = 1 
  AND `location`.`location_time` BETWEEN "2015-04-24 00:00:00" 
  AND "2015-04-25 23:59:59"
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you did a SQL Fiddle for this problem. http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Your problem is here: `->whereBetween('location.location_time', array( "2015-04-24 00:00:00", "2015-04-25 23:59:59" ))` try doing this : `->whereBetween('location.location_time', array(strtotime( "2015-04-24 00:00:00"),strtotime( "2015-04-25 23:59:59" )))`

Comment: I dont think you can use whereBetween withing a join clause. Gives you an error saying "Call to undefined
 method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\JoinClause::whereBetween()"